# I am making an ios app and I want to split the screen into 4 quadrants/buttons

Tags: swift, swift5

I am wondering how I can do this I pretty much want the full screen to be 4 giant buttons.

For example,

(bottom left will walk left) and (bottom right will walk right)

(top left will jump left) and (top right will jump right)

I currently have two giant buttons with left being jump left and right being jump right.
Thanks!

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if(location.x > self.frame.size.width/2){
            jumpRight()
        }

        else if(location.x < self.frame.size.width/2){
            jumpLeft()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Just create 4 `UIButtons`, add actions to them, and, using auto layout, size them appropriately?

Comment: I agree with @dfd , and if you want to make it dynamic then give them constraint according to the current height and width of `UIView`

Answer (score 0):

So I put together a little class that will help you out. I added some documentation to help you understand what is happening.

```
/// The cases of this enum correspond to the four cartesian quadrants.
enum Quadrant: CaseIterable {
    case one
    case two
    case three
    case four
}


/// Includes four methods corresponding to each quadrant. Methods are called when touches are registerd by the `FourButtonView`.
protocol FourButtonViewDelegate {
    func quadrantITouched(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    func quadrantIITouched(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    func quadrantIIITouched(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    func quadrantIVTouched(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
}



/// This view has four quadrants corresponding to the four quadrants of the cartesian plane.
class FourButtonView: UIView {

    var delegate: FourButtonViewDelegate?


    /// Calls the `FourButtonViewDelegate`'s `quadrantITouched(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)` method.
    /// - Parameter sender: Sender is the `UITapGestureRecognizer` from the button that was touched.
    @objc private func iTouched(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)  { delegate?.quadrantITouched(sender: sender) }


    /// Calls the `FourButtonViewDelegate`'s `quadrantITouched(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)` method.
    /// - Parameter sender: Sender is the `UITapGestureRecognizer` from the button that was touched.
    @objc private func iiTouched(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) { delegate?.quadrantIITouched(sender: sender) }


    /// Calls the `FourButtonViewDelegate`'s `quadrantITouched(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)` method.
    /// - Parameter sender: Sender is the `UITapGestureRecognizer` from the button that was touched.
    @objc private func iiiTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) { delegate?.quadrantIIITouched(sender: sender) }


    /// Calls the `FourButtonViewDelegate`'s `quadrantITouched(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)` method.
    /// - Parameter sender: Sender is the `UITapGestureRecognizer` from the button that was touched.
    @objc private func ivTouched(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) { delegate?.quadrantIVTouched(sender: sender) }


    // MARK: Sets up a button for every quadrant.
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        for quadrant in Quadrant.allCases {
            setupButtons(quadrant: quadrant)
        }
    }


    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    /// `setupButtons` sets up a button for a given quadrant.
    /// - Parameter quadrant: `quadrant` is a case of the `Quadrant` enum. It determines which button to set up.
    private func setupButtons(quadrant: Quadrant) {

        /// The button to be set up.
        let button: UIButton = getButton()

        /// The `backgroundColor` of the button.
        let backgroundColor: UIColor

        /// The `topAnchor` of the button.
        let top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor

        /// The `leftAnchor` of the button.
        let left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor

        /// The `bottomAnchor` of the button.
        let bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor

        /// The `rightAnchor` of the button.
        let right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor

        // MARK: Uses `quadrant` to determine top and bottom anchors.
        if quadrant == .one || quadrant == .two {
            top = topAnchor
            bottom = centerYAnchor
        } else {
            top = centerYAnchor
            bottom = bottomAnchor
        }

        // MARK: Uses `quadrant` to determine left and right anchors.
        if quadrant == .one || quadrant == .four {
            left = centerXAnchor
            right = rightAnchor

        } else {
            left = leftAnchor
            right = centerXAnchor
        }

        // MARK: Uses `quadrant` to determine color and `#selector(@objc method)` method.
        switch quadrant {
        case .one:
            backgroundColor = .red
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(iTouched), for: .allTouchEvents)
        case .two:
            backgroundColor = .blue
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(iTouched), for: .allTouchEvents)
        case .three:
            backgroundColor = .yellow
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(iTouched), for: .allTouchEvents)
        case .four:
            backgroundColor = .green
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(iTouched), for: .allTouchEvents)
        }

        // MARK: Sets `backgroundColor` of button.
        button.backgroundColor = backgroundColor

        // MARK: Activates layout constraints.
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top),
            button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left),
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom),
            button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right)
        ])
    }

    /// This function returns a `UIButton` that is prepared for setup with auto layout.
    private func getButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }

}
```